# Python 3.4 HTTP POST request with cookies

Tags: python, cookies

I'm having trouble constructing a method that will do a HTTP POST request with headers and data (username and password) and will retrieve the resulting cookies.

Here's my latest attempt so far:

```
def do_login(username, password):
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36",
               "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"}
    cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
    req = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    data = {"Username": username, "Password": password}
    req.open("http://example.com/login.php", data)
```

But I keep getting exceptions whenever I try to change the method. Also, will the response cookies be stored in the CookieJar `cj`, or is that used only for sending request cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research it seems that the data cannot be passed directly as an argument to `req.open`, and it needs to be converted to a URL-encoded string. Here's the solution that worked for me:

```
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36",
           "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"}

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
req = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
req.addheaders = list(headers.items())

# The data should be URL-encoded and then encoded using UTF-8 for best compatilibity
data = urllib.parse.urlencode({"Username": username, "Password": password}).encode("UTF-8")
res = req.open("http://example.com/login.php", data)
```